# Delete IN by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my `user_agreements` table:

```
|user_id|agreement_id|permitted              |
|-------|------------|-----------------------|
|114983 |1           |2022-07-14 11:52:37.763|
|114983 |2           |2022-07-14 12:18:42.100|
|114999 |1           |2022-07-14 12:18:52.397|
|115011 |1           |2022-07-18 22:39:22.360|
|115011 |2           |2022-07-18 22:39:22.717|
```

I want to delete this rows:

```
|user_id|agreement_id|permitted              |
|-------|------------|-----------------------|
|115011 |1           |2022-07-18 22:39:22.360|
|115011 |2           |2022-07-18 22:39:22.717|
```

Tried with this:

```
DELETE FROM user_agreements WHERE (user_id, agreement_id) IN ((115011, 1), (115011, 2))
```

But I am getting an error:

```
SQL Error [4145] [S0001]: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
```

Any ideas whats wrong there?

Comment: Tag your dbms name please

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: @TheImpaler sql server

Comment: You can't use `IN` with multiple columns. That's simply not valid SQL syntax. You can use a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to create a "table" in the query itself and join with it

Comment: As far as I remember SQL Server does not implement `IN` with tuples in any form (equality, inequality, joins, subqueries, or literals). Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB do... just fyi.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

DELETE
FROM
user_agreements
WHERE
user_id = 115011
and agreement_id IN (1,2)